# Web pages to print media -- solutions?

Tags: html, printing, media, mediawiki

I've been a big fan of MediaWiki and similar wiki-based text editors. I like the ability to quickly add text, collaborate, and share. However, there's always still the need for nicely formatted print output. Things like headers and footers (that say what I want them to say), page breaks, margins, etc.

Most solutions I've seen involve some sort of conversion to a intermediate print-media format (maybe MediaWiki to Microsoft Word or maybe some custom scripting that generates a PDF from the contents of a web page (with a lot of hard-coded references).

Is there any more generic solution that exists for this problem? Any framework that seeks to merge HTML and web content in general into a print media output format?

Any solutions, discussion regarding the pro's or con's, or whatever is welcome.

Thanks!

**Update:** I think CSS will only get me so far though... I've used CSS for similar type output (MediaWiki by default has a print format that hides much of the nav bar stuff). Think of a MediaWiki article though -- imagine me being able to tweak a tag in the content or something similar and now my margin is 1 inch instead of .5 inches. That's more along the lines of what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have heard of [PediaPress](http://pediapress.com/), a company that has done a "wiki to print" (i.e PDF, but also ODF) deal with the Wikimedia Foundation. (See ["Wikis Go Printable"](http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Press_releases/Wikis_Go_Printable).) Their code is designed to work with MediaWiki and is [open source](http://code.pediapress.com/).

But! It's even better than that. Check out this [bookmarklet](http://pediapress.com/collection/). You can use it to create PDFs or ODFs of any publicly-accessible MediaWiki page (maybe it needs the API to be enabled too...).  And you can bundle multiple pages, from a single MediaWiki or multiple MediaWikis, into a single document. It's pretty freaking awesome in my book. :)

ETA: PediaPress have put significant work into making something that looks *really* nice to read. It's not just the equivalent of MediaWiki's printable version converted to PDF.

Comment: Thanks -- I hadn't heard of them and that's really neat.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.princexml.com/

could be something for you. It converts xml and html pages to pdf documents.

Comment: +1 prince is absolutely amazing and worth the price! The quality and ease of xhtml to pdf conversion is stunning!

Answer (score 3):

Using [print CSS files](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) is a really slick approach to reformatting pages for printing.

A lot of people fall back to PDF because it *can* be more powerful and easier.

For most things, though, I think CSS markup is simpler and easier.

Look at the source for pages in StackOverflow and you'll see references to `media="print"` (print.css)--a set of styles applied only when a browser prints the page.

```
<link href="/Content/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" />
```

You can use these to hide navbars, ads (or show different ads). Do some basic pagination, etc.

If you need more control over things like margins, you have to go outside the browser (PDF, Word, XPS, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [MediaWiki to LaTeX converter](http://www.osresearch.net/wiki/index.php/LaTeX_and_MediaWiki) that tries to maintain the document structure of the source text.  The document is then typeset with pdflatex to produce a very high quality, paginated document.  Math markup is directly rendered by LaTeX, so the equations look great.  The LaTeX documentclass / stylesheet is configurable from specialized commands in the wiki to directly control margins, page layout, fonts, extra packages and so on.
This would fall in your second category of a custom script rather than a generic framework.

There are many others, such as the [Extension:Pdf_Export](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Pdf_Export) that uses [htmldoc](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1).  While it is more general, it does a very poor job of pagination and creates lots of widows and orphans, doesn't do optimal text justification and doesn't do indexes, figures, self-references, etc.  Additionally, if you use <math> markup in MediaWiki it only includes the low-res PNG files.

[princexml](http://www.princexml.com/license/) is specialized for MediaWiki and produces good looking documents, but isn't available under a Free license.  Since it is a closed-source product, your ability to control the output is limited.

Answer (score 1):

In general, use CSS print styles + some webpage-to-PDF tool ([headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#create_a_pdf_dom), [Electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-pdf), [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), [Prince XML](https://www.princexml.com/), or just your web browser's print to PDF feature if you don't need to automate it).

Specifically for MediaWiki, the [ElectronPdfService extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ElectronPdfService) does this for you. (Also, print styles are [being rewritten](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Reading/Web/Projects/Print_Styles) right now; check back in a month or two for improved presentation.)

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style type="text/css">
    @media print {
        /***css rules for print mode ***/
        aside#sidebar, header[role="banner"], footer, #comments, #respond, #header-v1, .breadcrumbs, #footer-v1,.topbar-v1,.header-v1,.fcbtnremove {
            display: none;
        }

        .container.content-xs {
            width: 98%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    }

    @media screen {
        /***css rules for screen , it is sometiems opposite of print mode ***/
        #header-v1, .breadcrumbs, #footer-v1,.topbar-v1,.header-v1 {
            display: block;
        }
    }

    table td , table th{text-align:center;vertical-align:middle}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mediawiki2latex project offers a solution.

Any MediaWiki page may be converted to PDF, Epub, Odt or LaTeX

It may be used online on a server hosted by the Wikimedia Foundation:

https://mediawiki2latex.wmflabs.org/

There is also a published article on the project

http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-2/tb107huenniger.pdf

The source is available under GPL. There is a well a Debian package:

```
sudo apt-get install mediawiki2latex
mediawiki2latex -u https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism -o output.pdf
evince output.pdf
```

Comment: The link to the question is nice, but a quality answer should contain the answer within stack overflow to prevent the knowledge from disappearing or becoming obsolete in case the linked website is taken down or is modified.